# How to solve bean exception in spring framework?

Tags: java, spring

```
package test;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import beans.Test;

public class Client {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    ApplicationContext ap=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("res/spring.xml");
    Test t=(Test)ap.getBean("t");
    t.printData();

  }
}
```

———————————————————————————————————

```
package beans;

public class Test {

  private String name;
  private int age;

  public Test(String name) {
    this.name=name;
  }

  public Test(int age) {
    this.age=age;
  }

  public void printData() {
    System.out.println("age="+age);
    System.out.println("name="+name);
  }
}
```

———————————————————————————————————-

> Jun 28, 2016 4:01:06 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
>   INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@138eb89: startup date [Tue Jun 28 16:01:06 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
>
> Jun 28, 2016 4:01:06 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
>   INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [res/spring.xml]
>
> Jun 28, 2016 4:01:06 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
>   INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@616ca2: defining beans [t]; root of factory hierarchy
>
> Jun 28, 2016 4:01:06 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory destroySingletons
>   INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@616ca2: defining beans [t]; root of factory hierarchy
>   Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 't' defined in class path resource [res/spring.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)**

———————————————————————————————————

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"

"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd 

(http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd)">

<beans>

  <bean id="t" class="beans.Test">

    <constructor-arg value="vikram" type="java.Lang.String" index="0"/>

    <constructor-arg value="123" type="int" index="1"/>

  </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: I checked everything like jar file,syntax.

Comment: The exception is telling you exactly what is wrong... There is no constructor with 2 parameters... You have 2 constructors either taking a string or an int, you don't have one taking both.

Comment: What do you think _Could not resolve matching constructor_ means?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Test` class has only a no-arg constructor, whereas in the XML configuration file, you specify that `Test` instances should be constructed by calling a constructor that accepts a `String` and an `int` as parameters.

You can either add a constructor in your `Test` class :

```
public class Test {
    private String name;
    private int age; 
    public Test(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    (...)
}
```

Or modify your Spring configuration file to inject the values via the setters, not the constructor :

```
<bean id="t" class="beans.Test">    
    <property name="name" value="vikram"/>    
    <property name="age"  value="123"/>
</bean>
```